# where did i go wrong in this piece of code

Tags: c, c-strings

```
int getstring(void)
{
  char *x;
  int i = 0;
  x = malloc(sizeof(char) + 1);
  char ch;
  while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
  {
     x[i] = getchar();
     x = realloc(x, sizeof(char) + i + 1);
     i++;
  }
  return *x;
}
```

I am trying to write a function to get string as an input after using this function in main I don't seem to get an output what is wrong with this?

Comment: Why do you return an `int`? Your function should return a `char *` and `return *x;` should be `return x;`.

Comment: You also forgot the 0-terminator of the string.

Comment: In addition to the previous comments: what do you mean by "not getting an input"? Do you mean that your return value is not what you expect?

Comment: I see a few things wrong, first you read the char twice instead of reading once and using the value you already read, so you may wind up skipping the value you are looking for in the loop.  Also you are realocating the wrong amount, should be `sizeof(char)*(i+1)` and finally why are you returning a character pointer in a function that returns int?  memory sizes depends on the system so it may or may not be the right value you are casting it to.

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond `sizeof(char)*(i+1)` should be `sizeof(char)*(i+2)`

Comment: In addition to the above comments, `ch` should be type `int`, not `char`, because the value `EOF` might not fit in a `char`.

Comment: `x[i] = getchar();` --> `x[i] = ch; x[i+1] = 0;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Since `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition, `i+2` is sufficient.

Comment: @KeithThompson I understand that. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//-----------------------------------
char* getstring(void)
  {
  char *x;
  int i = 0;
  x = malloc(sizeof(char));
  int ch;
  while ( ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) && (i<99))
  {
     x[i] = (char)ch;
     i++;
     x = realloc(x ,sizeof(char)*(i+1));
  }
  x[i]=0;
  return x;
  } 
//-----------------------------------
int main()
  {
  char *s;
  s=getstring();
  printf("\nYou entered : %s\n",s);
  free(s);
  return 0;
  }
//-----------------------------------

/* 

On Ubuntu linux you have to press ENTER and ctrl-d at the end of your keyboard input

output:

user@ubuntu1:~/Desktop/getstr$ ./tst
This is a test...

You entered : This is a test...



*/
```